# LIvewire 3 wire:submit not submiting the form

Tags: laravel, livewire-3

I am using Livewire 3.3 when I try to use wire:submit, it just refreshes the page and does not submit the form, even when I am using wire:navigate all over the project. below is my component code.

```
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use Livewire\Attributes\Validate;
use Livewire\Component;

class CreatePost extends Component
{
    #[Validate('required')]
    public $title = '';

    #[Validate('required')]
    public $content = '';

    public function save()
    {

        $this->validate();

        dd('all');

        return $this->redirect('/post/create', navigate: true);
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.create-post');
    }
}
```

Here is my blade file

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div>
    <form wire:submit="save">
        <input type="text" wire:model="title">
        <div>
            @error('title') <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
        </div>

        <input type="text" wire:model="content">
        <div>
            @error('content') <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
        </div>

        <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </form>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: make sure if you have <livewire:styles /> and <livewire:scripts /> added in your main blade file, where you are using livewire component.

Comment: @ZafeerAhmad I guess there is no need of <livewire:styles /> and <livewire:scripts /> in Livewire 3.*